# How to know if user is root or fakeroot?

Tags: c, busybox, fakeroot

I would like to know if user is root, without minding if that user is using a fakeroot-like tool or not.

I tried the functions `getuid()`, `geteuid()` and `getlogin()`, but when I launch `fakeroot` command each of these sends my own account information instead of `root`.

For this code:

```
printf("%d %d %s\n", getuid(), geteuid(), getlogin());
```

Here is what I get:

```
% fakeroot ./busybox rm 
1000 1000 julien
```

When I would like to get something like:

```
0 0 root
```

(the login would be enough)

Comment: By definition of `fakeroot` you should not be able to make programmatically the difference; at least if the binary is dynamically linked (I guess `fakeroot` uses `LD_PRELOAD` tricks).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch So why, when I enter `fakeroot whoami` do I get `root`?

Comment: That's a little odd -- `fakeroot` should be intercepting `get*uid` calls. Is `busybox` compiled against a static libc?

Comment: On my machine both `fakeroot id` and `fakeroot whoami` gives root answers.

Comment: @nneonneo Ah s***... Yes, that's why, but I have to compile it statically (it's for a school project) and they gave me this example to see if it was working...

Comment: @JulienFouilhé: if they think `fakeroot` will affect a statically linked binary, then they are certainly  mistaken. `fakeroot` has no effect on statically-linked binaries.

Comment: Yeah, I think they didn't compile it against a static libc and gave us a bad test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nneonneo got the reason right, but here's the solution: [Fakeroot-ng](http://fakeroot-ng.lingnu.com). It uses `ptrace` and system call interception, rather than `LD_PRELOAD` and library call interception, which makes it compatible with static linking, much more robust, and even able to handle calls made from inside libc (which otherwise would not be hookable).

Comment: Oh, that's cute. I figured it was possible with `ptrace` magic; it's nice to know that someone actually did it.

Comment: BTW right now it's fairly limited due to syscall differences between architectures and lack of resources to support all the archs Linux supports, but with the new "seccomp2" `ptrace` interfaces, it's possible to do syscall interception and filtering in an almost-arch-agnostic way. Adapting Fakeroot-ng to use the seccomp2 approach would make it a lot more portable and practical.

Comment: @nneonneo Thanks guys, I can't figure out which one of you two got my answer, works perfectly (has to be launched in sudo though) ;)

Comment: @R.. has your answer. I just gave the reason :)

Answer (score 6):

It looks as if your binary (`busybox`) is compiled against a static `libc`. `fakeroot` uses dynamic library preloading to intercept and replace calls to various `libc` functions, but this only works if your binary is dynamically linked to `libc`. If it is statically linked, the function calls are bound to the real calls inside the binary, so there is no way to intercept them.